# Unexpected result when extracting double values from CSV C++

Tags: c++, qt, csv, ubuntu

I have a problem reading .csv files using C++ Qt. Here is the CSV format:

```
0.2345;0.567;1.2456;...
```

And this is the code to read the CSV file:

```
void CSV::readCSV(std::istream &input, std::vector<double> &output) {
  std::string csvElement;
  while (std::getline(input, csvElement, ';')) {
    output.push_back(stod(csvElement));
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
```

The output is wrong. Could you help me for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? What are the actual values returned by stod()? Is the vector empty when passed to readCSV()? Does your locale use '.' as decimal separator?

Comment: As @roalz says, what does the debugger say - what have you tried??

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Including how you use the function you show, and how you print the output.

Comment: I suspect somewhere in your code you are converting or rounding the values to some integral type and then printing them out / converting to doubles.

Comment: the vector is not empty. it has any values.

Comment: yes i use '.' as decimal separator, 

what is the effect of it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect somewhere in your code you are converting values to some integral type and then printing them out or converting back to doubles. Something similar to:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4);
for (auto el : vec){
    int i = el;
    double d = i;
    std::cout << "Double: " << el << " Integer: " << i << " Double again: " << d << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: i never converted this one to integer
this is the code to call the method
'std::fstream fileBiasOutput("/home/fatchur/Qt5.7.0/Projects/genderRecognition/biasOutput.csv", ios::in);
     if (!fileBiasOutput.is_open())
        {
            std::cout << "File 5 not found!\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            return 1;
        }
     myCSV.readCSV(fileBiasOutput, myNet.biasOutput);
     cout << "6 ok";

Comment: when I run it on visual studio windows, the results are correct, but when i move to ubuntu, the problems appear.

Comment: `vector<double> bobotOutput;`

this is my definition in myNet class

Comment: and this is my code to call the methot

`myCSV.readCSV(fileBiasOutput, myNet.bobotOutput);`